# How to loop this data in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet (first row headers) where the 3 last columns are as follows: Component 1(column AW), Component 2 (AX) and Number of Components (AY). Number of components value is either 1 or 2. If "Number of components" is 2 then I would like to copy the entire row and paste it twice to the last row of the same worksheet.
If "Number of components"is 1 then I would only like to copy it once.
Earlier there is also a column M that contains the article number and for each copied row I would like the value in column M to be replaced by the value from the corresponding row of column Component 1 / Component 2.

[image: For example]

For example in this row the article number in column M is x. As "Number of components" is 2, I would like this whole row to be pasted twice to the last row of the worksheet. By the first time it is pasted, I need column M value to be replaced by 205334 (Component 1 value) and when it is pasted second time I need column M value to be replaced by 96423 (Component 2 value). Is it possible to loop this way? The worksheet has more than a 1000 rows.

I have written the following code to do the copy/paste part, however I'm having trouble to replace the value from Column M with the value from Columns Component 1 and 2.

```
Dim lastcol As Range
Dim lColumn As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Long

lColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set lastcol = Cells(2, lColumn)

For i = 2 To Rows.Count
    If lastcol.Value = 2 Then
        Cells(i, lColumn).EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Copy Sheets("Filtersets Database (2)").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Cells(i, lColumn).EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Copy Sheets("Filtersets Database (2)").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Cells(i, lColumn).EntireRow.Select
    ElseIf lastcol.Value = 1 Then
        Cells(i, lColumn).EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Copy Sheets("Filtersets Database (2)").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
Next i
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.  To get advice you need to present us with the code you have written and explain what is not working.

Comment: and yes, it is possible, you only need one loop to iterate trough column AY values

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your answers. I've updated the post with what I've written (sorry for the format, don't know how to add it better). I can't get the value from Column M to get updated by the value from the "Component1&2" columns.

Comment: Are you doing this all on one sheet or are you copying from one sheet to another? By the way, why are you looping through every single row on the sheet?

Comment: Hi Norie, I´m doing it all on one sheet. I've just realized this loop never ends, so it must be wrong. It's my first vba project ever and I'm not really sure what I'm doing :D so if it's looping through every single row, it has to be my mistake

Comment: As a general rule, avoid `.Select` and `.Activate` wherever possible.  You can make `.Value = .Value` references or `.Copy` would replace the `.Select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySomeThings()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngDst As Range
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet    ' Sheets("Filtersets Database (2)")

    lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set rngDst = ws.Range("A" & lastrow + 1)

    For i = 2 To lastrow

        With ws
            If .Cells(i, lastcol).Value = 2 Then
                .Rows(i).Copy rngDst
                .Cells(rngDst.Row, "M").Value = .Cells(i, lastcol - 2)
                Set rngDst = rngDst.Offset(1)
                .Rows(i).Copy rngDst
                .Cells(rngDst.Row, "M").Value = .Cells(i, lastcol - 1)
                Set rngDst = rngDst.Offset(1)
            ElseIf .Cells(i, lastcol) = 1 Then
                .Rows(i).Copy rngDst
                .Cells(rngDst.Row, "M").Value = .Cells(i, lastcol - 2)
                Set rngDst = rngDst.Offset(1)
            End If
        End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, amazing, it works perfectly! Thank you so much :)